# Another failed review audit for low quality posts

Tags: discussion, review, flagging, review-audit, disputed-review-audits

I failed a [review audit for an answer which is actually a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/920052).  The user claimed to have insufficient reputation to leave a comment, but he/she wanted to stop other users from answering the question (with a *legitimate* reason).

Despite my appreciation of his/her courage, given that I was doing a "*review*", I clicked "Deletion" with "No comments needed" because IMHO, to arouse others' attention for content problem of the question, flagging the question would be a better option than leaving a comment as an answer.  Then, the system alerted me to this review audit failure.

Should I let him go the next time by clicking "Looks OK"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you did right. That's not an answer in any way, and voting to delete it is the correct action.

The poor audit system was misled by the post having a score of +5. Since it doesn't know any mathematics, the only criterion it has to pick posts for audits is the vote tally. Sometimes that leads to wrong-headed audits. But that's at least as much an issue with the voters as with the audit system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.